# Trim first 6 characters from Folder Names [AppleScript]

Tags: applescript

I've found an AppleScript online which trims the first characters from a FILENAME, however, it does not seem to work on FOLDERS.

How could this be modified to rename folder names?

```
set whichFile to choose file with multiple selections allowed
repeat with aFile in whichFile
    tell application "Finder"
        set filename to name of aFile
        set name of aFile to ((characters 7 thru -1 of filename) as string)
    end tell
end repeat
```

Thank You!

Comment: Must this solution be apple script? I can make a bash script for this in a jiffy if that's acceptable

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to trim the first six characters using [Namechanger](http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/).

I apologize if you specifically need to use AppleScript, but [Namechanger](http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/) is a useful app for renaming files & folders. It has treated me well.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This applies to the files selected in Finder and works with both folders and regular files:

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (get selection)
        set name of f to (text 7 thru -1 of (get name of f))
    end repeat
end tell
```

You could also run a command like this in Terminal:

```
cd ~/containing/folder;for f in *;do mv "$f" "${f:6}";done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set whichFolder to choose folder with multiple selections allowed
repeat with aFolder in whichFolder
    tell application "Finder"
        set folderName to name of aFolder
        set name of aFolder to (text 7 thru -1 of folderName)
    end tell
end repeat
```